# How to add independent input variables in RNN model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, deeplearning4j

I have customer purchase history and some independent variables associated with each product that customer bought. I am trying to predict the next best predict for customers.

T  Customer Input1 Input2 ...... Input10 PrdouctBought
 1    cust1
 2    cust1
 3    cust1
 4    cust1
 1    cust2
 2    cust2
 3    cust2
 4    cust2

I have restricted each customer purchase history to 4 so that we can fix batch_size=4 and we get away with the problem of model taking in account of last product of previous customer.
What I am not able to do is how to incorporate these input variables to make RNN predict the next best product for that customer.

Comment: I have tried to model it using RNN of Tensorflow but can't figure out where and how do I add my input variables, hence not able to proceed any further